# cmake building external library from github submodule

Tags: c++11, cmake

I am trying to build a sample c++ project with cmake which depends on the external Pisatche library hosted in [github](https://github.com/oktal/pistache). Installation guide list the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/oktal/pistache.git
git submodule update --init

cd pistache
mkdir -p {build,prefix}
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DPISTACHE_BUILD_EXAMPLES=true \
    -DPISTACHE_BUILD_TESTS=true \
    -DPISTACHE_BUILD_DOCS=false \
    -DPISTACHE_USE_SSL=true \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/../prefix \
    ../
make -j
make install
```

I would like to install this library from inside cmake and then link it to my executable. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: I haven't really started since I don't know how. So no error message yet.

Comment: You want to look at `ExternalProject` then.